# Is there a way in haskell to compactly and efficiently compare by multiple parameters and in different orders

Tags: haskell, compare

Suppose we have a list of tuples and we need to find maximum on some criterion. The criterion is the following - most important is the first element of the tuple (more is better) less important is second element (less is better).

I know two ways of expressing this in Haskell.

First one is to create a function that would make all the comparisons and return `(EQ, LT, GT)`

```
compareSol (s1, w1) (s2, w2) = if weightComp == EQ then sizeComp else weightComp where 
    weightComp = compare w1 w2
    sizeComp = compare (Map.foldl' (+) 0  s2) (Map.foldl' (+) 0  s1)
```

The second one is to use `comparing` from `Data.Ord` and give it a function that would return a score `\ (x, y) -> (x, 1 / y)` Which is I think more declarative, but would require more computations (`1 / y`)

Is there a way of expressing this in both declarative and efficient way, like is sql?

Comment: The code you show makes the second argument to be more important, but you say otherwise in the text -- which is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't understand the precise ordering you want, but probably some variation of the following is what you are looking for

```
compareSol (s1, w1) (s2, w2) = compare (w1, sum s2) (w2, sum s1)
```

the above is equivalent to

```
compareSol (s1, w1) (s2, w2) 
   | w1 < w2   = LT
   | w1 > w2   = GT
   | otherwise = compare (sum s2) (sum s1)
```

or, fully expanded,

```
compareSol (s1, w1) (s2, w2) 
   | w1 < w2 = LT
   | w1 > w2 = GT
   | sum s1 < sum s2 = GT
   | sum s1 > sum s2 = LT
   | otherwise = EQ
```

Feel free to swap the comparisons around so to meet your goal.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `comparing` and `Down` from `Data.Ord` with `<>` from `Data.Monoid`:

```
compareSol = comparing snd <> comparing (Down . sum . fst)
```

In this case you can also use the simpler `flip` instead of `Down`:

```
compareSol = comparing snd <> flip (comparing (sum . fst))
```

---

This is a combination of a few features.

`Data.Ord.comparing` compares two values based on a function of those values—`comparing f` is equivalent to `` compare `on` f `` using `Data.Function.on`.

```
comparing :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
```

The `Monoid` instance for `Ordering` gives you lexicographical ordering.

```
LT <> x = LT
GT <> x = GT
EQ <> x = x
```

The `Monoid` instance for functions lets you compose comparison functions of type `a -> Ordering`, or in this case `a -> a -> Ordering`.

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)
-- instance Monoid c => Monoid (a -> b -> c)
-- instance Monoid Ordering
-- instance Monoid (a -> b -> Ordering)
-- instance Monoid (a -> a -> Ordering)  given  a ~ b
```

And finally, the `Down` newtype inverts the ordering of the type it wraps, giving you reversed comparison for free:

```
     0 <       1  ==  True
Down 0 <  Down 1  ==  False
     0 >       1  ==  False
Down 0 >  Down 1  ==  True
```